# Why Mongodb is not making data folder by its own?

Tags: database, mongodb, installation, nosql

I know that in windows when I run mongodb I need data/db folder in c: then why mongodb automatically creates it and gives error

Comment: I would provide the error in your question. It may just be a permissions error when it tried to create the directory.

Comment: MongoDB does not create your `dbpath` itself. You would need to create it yourself and give it the proper permissions. This is so that MongoDB don't overwrite things by mistake.